# How to access just My Drive not the Shared Drives?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I got a questions regarding the `DriveApp.folders()` function for the google Scripts. I just implemented a script which add a description to all my files, that the last change date will get updated. For this I used the `DriveApp.folders()` with `.getfiles()`. Now my Problem: this function access all folders, even the shared folders, but it should only access the Folders in My Drive? How can I handle this?

I tried already the `.getOwner()` function, but with this i get 'DriveUser' as Answer with some shared drive folders.

I tried also to get the access by `.getFolderbyID()` but there is no ID for my drive.

Here is my code:

```
function writeDescription() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var count = 0;

  while (folder.hasNext()){

    var ordner = folder.next();
    var files = ordner.getFiles();
    Logger.log(ordner.getName())
    //Logger.log(files)

      while (files.hasNext()){

        
          var file = files.next();
          count = count +1;
          file.setDescription(" "); 
          //Logger.log(file.getName());
        }
    } 

  Logger.log(count); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getOwner() and compare to your email to get only the ones you own.

Comment: Hi Serge, this was a good hint, but i also get for the shared drives and my drive folders "Drive User" as answer, but not for all, sometimes i get "null" back. Br Launga